# How can I acess localised strings in a custom search suggestions provider?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I have a custom search suggestions provider for my application's `SearchView`. The suggestions show up just fine but the suggestion names are hard-coded. I'd like to fetch localised strings from my `strings.xml` file but I need access to the activity context which I don't have in my search provider.

My search provider is mapped to my `SearchView` using the `searchables.xml` file as recommended in the Android Developer docs. Here's my searchable configuration:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="artist, track informations..."
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:queryAfterZeroResults="true"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.testapp.providers.QuickSearchProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="3" />
```

...and here's the actual search provider:

```
public class QuickSearchProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {

  public final static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.testapp.providers.QuickSearchProvider";
  public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES | DATABASE_MODE_2LINES;

  public QuickSearchProvider() {
    setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
  }

  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String sel,
      String[] selArgs, String sortOrder) {

      MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { 
          BaseColumns._ID,
          SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
          SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
          SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1,
          SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION});

      cursor.addRow(new Object[] { 0, "Plants", "Search Plants", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search, Search.SEARCH_PLANTS_ACTION});
      cursor.addRow(new Object[] { 1, "Birds", "Search Birds", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search, Search.SEARCH_BIRDS_ACTION });

      return new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] { cursor });
  }

}
```

I'd like to get localised strings from my string resource file for those terms like "Plants" and "Birds".

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

String value = this.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.Plants)

Comment: Man, was it as simple as that?!